# Ajax removes entire HTML table instead of refreshing it

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm building a project, and using Ajax for the first time. Currently, I have a table of data and I have used Ajax to add and delete records from the table without having to reload the page. The next step I want to do is to refresh the data in the table when data is added or removed from the data.

In my Ajax code, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form#TesttableIndexForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/testing/save_ajax_data',
        type:'POST',
        data: $("form#TesttableIndexForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#testtable").replaceWith(data);
        },

    });     
});

$('a.deleteajax').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var answer = confirm("Delete this record?")
    if (answer){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/testing/delete_ajax_data/',
            type:'GET',
            data: $(this).attr("href"),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#testtable").replaceWith(data);
            },
        });
    }

    return false;  
});

});
```

The ID of the table is `#testtable`. I've added the `$("#testtable").replaceWith(data);` inside the `success` part of the code so that when the data is added or removed the table is then refreshed.

However, even though data can still be removed and added using that Ajax code, when either event happens the table vanishes. When I reload the page manually the table reappears with the amended data.

I am using CakePHP, and the data from the table is generated from a database. Would this be causing me problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what response you get from `/testing/save_ajax_data`, check it by putting `alert(data)` just above `$("#testtable").replaceWith(data);` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was.

In my Ajax file, I added `var loadUrl = "/test-area/table/";` which is a URL to a controller which will load the HTML table. I had to then create a function within my controller to basically query the database again:

```
function testtable() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->loadModel('Testtable');

    $testing = $this->Testtable->find('all');
    $this->set('testing', $testing);
}
```

What I did notice when playing about with this is that if you don't specify `$this->layout = 'ajax';` it will load the page with the default layout. This then breaks the page completely. So I created a completely blank layout file called `ajax`.

Then, in the ajax code, I removed:

```
$("#testtable").replaceWith(data);
```

With:

```
$("#testtable").load(loadUrl + "#testtable");
```

With all these things together, when a record is added or removed, the table will then reload without problems.